# Javascript/JQuery function not triggered after .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-hover, jquery-click-event

When a user clicks the "search" button in my ASP.NET application, a temporary "spinner" div is loaded. Then when the search (finally) completes, the contents of the spinner div are replaced by the HTML returned by the `SubmitSearch` method.

```
$("#spinner").load("@Url.Action("SubmitSearch","Search")");
```

I also have this JavaScript file that is loaded in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".card--result").hover(function () {
        alert("hover");
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    });

    $(".card--result").click(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
        window.open(url, "_self");
    });
});
```

However, the problem is that a div with `card--result` class is part of the new HTML that gets added to the page after the `.load` method succeeds.

**How can I register the `.hover` and `.click` functions so that they are actually triggered on the newly loaded HTML elements?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for this.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

```
$(document).on("click", ".card--result", function() {
   var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
   window.open(url, "_self");
});
```

and for the cursor part I guess CSS would be enough

```
.card--result {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Already answered a tone of times.